# How to post an HTML tag when asking question

Tags: discussion

How can I post the HTML tag when pasting the tags here in the body? It displays the output when I am pasting the HTML body.

Like in the below example: This should be a long div tags... but it displays the output of the HTML only.

```
<div _ngcontent-c23="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 space-column ng-star-inserted" data-index="0">
    <cws-cardbox _ngcontent-c23="" _nghost-c28="" class="Investment0" ng-reflect-ng-class="Investment0" ng-reflect-status="A"><div _ngcontent-c28="" class="card-status active" ng-reflect-klass="card-status" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
</div>

<div _ngcontent-c28="" class="card-box">

    <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy">
        <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="planType">Investment</span>
        <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="product">
            Inheritance
        </span>
        <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-no">
            <label _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-label">
                Policy No.:
            </label>
            <span _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-value">8000000001</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c23="" class="divider"></div>

    <!--bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }-->

    <!--bindings={
        "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><div _ngcontent-c23="" class="policy-content ng-star-inserted">

    </div>

</div>

</cws-cardbox>
</div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I know it now, The button you mentioned are not displaying in chrome. I tried it in IE and I can now see.....

Comment: The HTML content does not seem to be *well formed*. For instance, tag `cws-cardbox` seems to be overlapping with other tags. Using a validator is recommended, e.g. the *[W3C Markup Validation Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service)*

Comment: *[Well-formed element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element)*

Answer (score -3):

While raising questions related to `selenium` inevitably you need to provide the relevant *HTML* which helps the contributors to construct canonical answers based on [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

As per your relevant HTML there are three different ways to post the *HTML* so it renders properly within the question area as follows:

- First Procedure - Marking the HTML as *Code Sample* using the `{}` control:

[image: Code_Sample]

- Second Procedure - Surrounding the HTML with *Triple Ticks*:

[image: triple_ticks]

- Third Procedure - Embedding the HTML as *JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet* and using *Tidy*:

[image: HTML_Snippet]